# Is it possible for in app purchase in ios to use account specific subscription?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, payment

**Is it possible for in app purchase in ios to use  account specific subscription?**

For example:

Let us say, I have one requirement that user have to subscribe to generate ticket (ticket is nothing but a secret code). 
Now if user 'A' subscribe once from one device let say 'Device-1', then 'A' can login with other device let say 'Device-2', so in other device(Device-2) it should not be ask for purchase. Because 'A' is the same user who already subscribed in previous device (Device-1).

Apple track purchases as device specific not account.
Is there any way or any idea to achieve above problem?

Comment: I think you must read consumable and non consumable concepts for that.

Comment: Sounds like what the "restore purchase" option is for.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Yes, but there is one more challenge that subscription will expire every month and user have to renew it. Consumable and non consumable subscriptions are not fit in this problem.

Comment: yes decez, restore purchase is a solution when user changes the device. but what if device is same and users are object of change?
Let me take an example: suppose there is one device(Device 1). now consider a user (User A) which uses 'device 1', do subscription, generate ticket and log out. 
Now 'User B' login to 'device 1'(same device) with its id/password but user B is not subscribed to generate ticket code and use 'user A's' subscription freely. This should not be happened.

Answer (score 0):

No,apple only track the device based purchase
i had same type of problem but i have the backend with webapi service so i can handle with when the user purchase subscription then i will mark that user in our web server as their subscriber when he login into another device with that user-id  i will manage to give them back their subscription.
cheers